# When shall i release these objects in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, object, release, retain, dealloc

I'm new in programming obj-c. So, when shall i release the defined objects?
Do i have to release urlRequest, response, data and content?

```
- (NSString*)getContentFromUrl:(NSURL*)url {
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
        [urlRequest setURL:url];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = NULL;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest 
                            returningResponse:&response 
                            error:nil];
    NSString *content = NULL;
    if ([response statusCode] >= 200) {
        content = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
    }
    [content autorelease];
    return content;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to release `urlRequest` only. `response`, `data` are created already as autoreleased objects and `content` receives autorelease message before return (I'd suggest changing last two lines with just `return [content autorelease]`).

It's also more common to initialize object pointers to `nil` rather than `NULL`.

Cocoa has a convention if you call `alloc`, `copy`, `retain` or `new` on any of objects while initializing or reassigning them you have to `release` them unless they receive `autorelease` message after creation.

You can see from your code that only `urlRequest` and `content` variables are created using `alloc` method, hence they have to be [auto]released.

**update minding the comments**

If you have `urlRequest` as an instance variable the previously initiated variable can shadow the ivar and you may get into various troubles (like `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`). You better pick a different name for your local variable.

Comment: Okay thank you.

it works for now, but if i release urlRequest and execute the method more than one time, i get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Depends on where you are releasing the `urlRequest` variable.

Comment: You can release it right after `data` variable initialization.

Comment: But when i send [urlRequest release] or autorelease after data variable initialization, it breaks with an 'Thread 5: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"'

Comment: i dont know if i'm really the owner of the urlRequest... because if i retain urlRequest on initialization, i can send the release-message after data initialization. (very weird, but on this way i can understand the memory management)

Comment: You should not call additional `retain`, because you initialize `urlRequest` with `alloc` and `init`. There's gotta be something else wrong. May be you have `urlRequest` as an instance variable?